# Amazon RDS batch insert slower than local database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I wrote a node program that batch insert to database and do a console log for every completed insert.

```
function insert(){
    var sql = "insert into todo (user, content) values (xx, xx);" +
              "insert into todo (user, content) values (xx, xx);" +
              "insert into todo (user, content) values (xx, xx);" +       
    (.... 4000 lines of insert)

    db.insert(sql,function success(){
        console.log('done');
    });
}

for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
    insert();
}
```

I have 2 setup of this:

```
1) Local machine to local DB. 

2) Amazon EC2 Micro Instance to Amazon RDS Micro Instance from same region

*Both my.cnf leave to default with only max_allowed_packet=500m set.
```

The result is by the time RDS complete one insert, my local machine has completed 24 insert.  I tried to upgrade my RDS to small instance, it make no different.

My question is why is amazon rds slower in this case. Any solution for this?

Comment: The test you describe does not seem to be an apples-to-apples comparison.  Testing a local DB removes any network latencies and throughput limitations.

Comment: @Bob Kinney. You are right for that, but I assume EC2 to RDS with the same region should have ok network lantencies. I believe the result can be better, even is cloud database, unless there's something I missed out.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be related to the micro instance performance. After some testing, we moved completely away from micro instances and switched to small instances. On the other hand, I have not found any problems regarding the RDS speed, even with small instances.

Have a look at how the EC2 micro instances work and where they should be used:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html

From how I understand your test case, your setup mostly looks like the second figure, and this should not be suitable for micro instances. Try using a small instance and compare the results there. Even if it is still slower than on your local machine, you will have comparable results then.

Comment: I wished that to be the case too, but I did upgrade to small instance and didn't notice much different between.

Comment: I can confirm the very poor performance of the micro instances. It's pretty bad to give them as trial because it definitely doesn't  encourage you to continue using the service.